# Merely Players they

Tags: word, knowledge, outer-space

What is the relationship shared by the following celebrities?

- Deneb
- Betelgeuse
- Antares
- Aldebaran
- Altair
- Rigel
- Adhara

<sub>(besides the obvious fact that each is an astronomical object comprising a luminous spheroid of plasma held together by its gravity)</sub>

Hint 1:

> The wording of the question is designed to confirm the solution but it does not actually indicate the method of solving. In fact, the puzzle might have been easier without the question.

Hint 2:

> The answer is a 7-letter [word](/questions/tagged/word).

Comment: Can you give some players that **don't** match this pattern? Else, say they all don't have the letter "j".

Comment: @NumberBasher While that might be helpful, in the absence of any such hint I'd recommend trying to look for a *positive* relationship rather than a negative one - this should lead you to some more satisfactory possibilities (everyone would be disappointed if the answer was just 'there's no J' and the downvotes would start pouring in once the answer was known, so I think it unlikely this is cap's intention). Remember there's going to be [a hint in the title](https://philosiblog.com/2013/04/23/all-the-worlds-a-stage-and-all-the-men-and-women-merely-players/). Use that to guide your thinking...

Comment: Something to do with famous Shakespeare characters in the stars?

Comment: Znlor fbzrguvat ncbat gur yvarf bs, "Vs lbh punatr 1 yrggre gb nabgure yrggre vg fcryyf 7 zrzoref bs n fcbegf grnz?

Comment: Is the checksum 64?

Comment: Seemly Earthly Prey?  The title looks like an anagram.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a Ford Cygnus. `:)` On a more productive note: With [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_brightest_stars), these seven celebs easily map to what the second hint alludes to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all

> **CO-STARS**

We should start by

> taking the [Bayer designations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_designation) of these stars
>  Deneb = **α Cygni**
>  Betelgeuse = **α Orionis**
>  Antares = **α Scorpii**
>  Aldebaran = **α Tauri**
>  Altair = **α Aquilae**
>  Rigel = **β Orionis**
>  Adhara = **ε Canis Majoris**
>
>  Next, we should index into the constellation names based on the assigned Greek letters
>  α **C**ygni, α **O**rionis, α **S**corpii, α **T**auri, α **A**quilae, β O**r**ionis, ε Cani**s** Majoris
>  spelling out **CO-STARS**.